# How to set value in @Html.TextBoxFor in Razor syntax?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.textboxfor

I have created an text-box using Razor and trying to set `value` as follows.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Destination, new { id = "txtPlace", value= "3" })
```

I have tried appending `value` with `@`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.Destination, new { id = "txtPlace", @value= "3" })
```

even though it renders html `input` tag with empty `value`

```
<input id="txtPlace" name="Destination" type="text" value 
   class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-mini" >
```

What am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a default value with Html.TextBoxFor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034986/how-to-set-a-default-value-with-html-textboxfor)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a lower case v.

You need to set it to Value and it should fix your issue:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Destination, new { id = "txtPlace", Value= "3" })
```

Comment: how to set Value for @Html.TextBoxFor using $('#id').val("myvalue") .Any clue?

Answer (score 10):

I tried replacing `value` with `Value` and it worked out. It has set the `value` in `input` tag now.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Destination, new { id = "txtPlace", Value= "3" })
```

Comment: Although it will work, I think a more neat way is to initialize the Destination property of your model in the Controller.

Comment: @Romias it depends on the use case. For example, I have a model that is used for both an edit dialog and a search dialog. In the edit dialog, it is OK. Default values are initialized properly and even `int` properties appear initialized with `0`. However, for the search dialog, I need all the fields to be initially empty for obvious reasons. That is why the use of setting the value in the razor view makes sense. I don't know the real use case of the original question, though.

Answer (score 8):

It is going to write the value of your property `model.Destination`

This is by design.  You'll want to populate your Destination property with the value you want in your controller before returning your view.

Comment: It doesn't always.  If your route object contains a Destination parameter then MVC will use this in preference to the Destination property in your Model.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251241/textboxfor-showing-wrong-value/7251446

Answer (score 6):

I tried replacing `value` with `Value` and it worked out. It has set the `value` in `input` tag now.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me, in MVC5:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", id = "theID" , @Value="test" })
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Tries with following it will definitely work:

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Destination, new { id = "txtPlace", Value= "3" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Destination, new { id = "txtPlace", @Value= "3" })

<input id="txtPlace" name="Destination" type="text" value="3" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-mini" >
```