# EditorFor changing value in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm running into a problem where it appears as if the value of the model is being changed with in the view:

View:

```
@model StudentTransportation.Models.PassengerVM

<div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PassengerID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PassengerID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PassengerID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
 <div>
```

Model:

```
 public class PassengerVM
 {
    public int PassengerID { get; set; }
 }

 public PassengerVM()
 {
    PassengerID = 0;
 }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddCompanion()
    {
        var companion = new PassengerVM();

        return View("AddCompanion", companion);
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="PassengerID">PassengerID</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PassengerID must be a number." data-val-required="The PassengerID field is required." id="PassengerID" name="PassengerID" type="number" value="1">
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="PassengerID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
  </div>
```

The value is set to 0 by default, however in the view it appears to display as 1. Any suggestions?

When I add @Model.PassengerID into the HTML, it displays the correct value. However the textbox still displays 1

Comment: can we see the controller? are you assinging PassengerVM object before sending it to view?

Comment: @vgSefa I've added the controller code.

Comment: What happens if you change PassenderID to be a full property, so you can put breakpoints in it?  You should be able to see what sets the value to 1.

Comment: @MobyDisk I've tried adding Model.PassengerID into the HTML and it displays 0 (the correct value). I've debugged in the view and the Model in my watch has the correct value.

Comment: This may sound silly: What is the URL to the page?  And is PassengerID a parameter to the method in the controller?

Comment: @MobyDisk http://localhost:8000/TestApp/Admin/AddCompanion. No it doesn't appear to be. Do you think it could be a Visual Studio problem?

Comment: I just posted an answer but maybe it is wrong based on your reply here since I don't see PassenderID in your URL.  Try renaming PassengerID in your model to something else, like "PassengerShoeSize" and bind to that.  Does the problem go away?  If so, then my solution is correct, although I don't see where PassengerID is in your example.  If renaming does not fix it, then my answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @MobyDisk it appears as if you've found the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have another property named @PassengerID somewhere.  When you do this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PassengerID
```

the "model" is an object of type HtmlHelper, not PassengerVM!  The HtmlHelper class searches for properties first on the URL, then on the HTTP post parameters, then finally on your model.  However, @Model.PassengerId goes straight to your model of type PassengerVM.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Pet pet = new Pet();
    pet.Id = 7;

    // If you navigate to /Pet/Edit/1 then @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)
    // will show the Pet Id of "1" not "7"
    return View(pet);
}
```

Take a look at some other examples where people had similar problems:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx

[TextBoxFor - Showing Wrong Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251241/textboxfor-showing-wrong-value)

Comment: So did you figure out where was PassengerID coming from then?  It didn't look like it came from the URL.  I had a coworker just tell me "and that's why I don't like to use the HTML Helpers..."

Comment: Yeah, turns out it was the link that another method was calling. It was passengerID instead of PassengerID, which made us think it wouldn't affect it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I can't add this as a comment but have you tried...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PassengerID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

instead of EditorFor

Comment: Yes, I have. The value is still 1. I've spoken to the other devs on the team and they think it's odd.

Comment: It looks like its displaying the length of the value, just looking at the code, and not writing it out myself, this looks wrong  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } } and if you set the value to 100 you would get 3 maybe? A missing null parameter?

Comment: I've changed the value to 10000 and the value is still 1. (Odd, I know). The code that you referred to was the scaffold template from MVC.

Comment: I just tried your code and I cannot reproduce this, it's 0 for me.  It's got to be the case that it's being set somewhere else.