# id is taken from the URL parameter, and not from the Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have [this same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7251446/831138) with my code, and I want to avoid the side effects without changing my variable name.

That is:

My URL is `(...)/MarriageByPersonId?id=231`

This goes search the `Person` and creates a new `Marriage` object (with `Marriage.id = null`).

It finally reaches the view with `Model=Marriage`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.id, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.id)
</div>
```

This `form-group`, although `id` is `null` in the model, shows the `id` from the `GET`. This behavior, in my case is unexpected and undesired.

Is there a way to block this undesired behavior and use the model only?

---

**UPDATE**

The relevant part of the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MarriageByPersonId(int id)
{
    var person = _personRepository.GetById(id);
    var marriage = _marriageRepository.GetById(person.marriage_id);
    return Marriage(marriage);
}

private ActionResult Marriage(Marriage marriage)
{
    var people = _personRepository.GetAll();

    ViewBag.men = Utils.GetPersonsSelectListByGender(people, isMale: true);
    ViewBag.women = Utils.GetPersonsSelectListByGender(people, isMale: false);

    return View(nameof(MarriageController.Marriage), marriage);
}
```

Comment: are you submitting the form via POST? is the receiving action marked as POST-only?

Comment: @trailmax The entry point is a GET action: `(...)/MarriageByPersonId?id=231`. This then calls another private function that shows the view. The view shows the form, with the invalid `id` (which is taken from the GET parameter instead of `@model Marriage`).

Comment: Can you show your controller methods

Comment: @PatrickMcvay I've updated the question with the controller methods. I've solved it by changing `id` to `personId` in the `HttpGet` action. I consider it a "dangerous gotcha". It's not intuitive, and I'm still interested in a generic way to avoid this.

Comment: I don't know that this will work, but have you tried accepting an id param in the Marriage action? private ActionResult Marriage(int id, Marriage marriage)

Comment: @PatrickMcvay I can't do that because there are many entry points (actions) that lead into `ActionResult Marriage(Marriage marriage)`. To goal of this is to unify the work of showing the page, even if there are several ways to reach it (son_id, husband_id, wife_id ...). Every action gets the `Marriage` object from the database in its own way, and then gives the retrieved object to `Marriage` in order to visualize it.

Comment: What about using Redirect to Action like.... return RedirectToAction(nameof(MarriageController.Marriage), "Marriage",
marriage); and also @ssmith 's answer is a viable option even though there is another attribute [FromBody] which I use quite often.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay The decision came from this [other question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42225936/831138), where given the circumstances I was told to use a private method instead of `RedirectToAction`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an attribute on your id parameter to specify its source. If you don't want it bound, just choose a source that won't be populated. Your options are

- [FromHeader]
- [FromQuery]
- [FromRoute]
- [FromForm]

You don't want [FromQuery] obviously, since that's the behavior you're looking to avoid. Try [FromForm] and if it's not present there, it should remain unbound.

Your code would then look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MarriageByPersonId([FromForm]int id)
{
    var person = _personRepository.GetById(id);
    var marriage = _marriageRepository.GetById(person.marriage_id);
    return Marriage(marriage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HhtpGet will always get parameters from URL. Try make another method with HttpPost and post your model to that method then it should work.

Or another idea is try to remove httpGet and try use it without it. I had similar problem. Seems that default mvc binder is confused when you have same property name in query and in model.